# Why is rm -rf ~/.Trash/* much faster than clicking "empty trash"?

Tags: terminal, trash

On a Mac computer, when you write

```
 rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

in the terminal, it almost instantly deletes all the files in the Trash.

But when I click "empty trash", it takes forever to delete them all.

Comment: Have you set `securely empty trash` or an equivalent feature on? If so, the command is as Claudio says which the GUI could be doing a hook that does a zero-out pass.

Comment: How long is forever? How many files do you have? It could just be that the GUI is stuttering on updating the UI if you have tons of small files. If naively implemented, the UI could remove one icon per file deleted from the filesystem, which is slow.

Answer (score 6):

When you use `rm -rf ~/.Trash/*` you're directly using a system call that unlinks these files from the filesystem, freeing the space allocated by them. If you use a GUI tool instead (I suppose you are referring to it when you say "click empty trash") it is probably saving or moving these files somewhere else so you can possibly undelete them, which is not directly possible using the shell command line. That should be the reason it is faster, but it wouldn't explain the GUI tool taking "forever".

How many times faster do you perceive the command line erase comparing to the GUI tool?

Comment: The command line would be less than 5 seconds. Compare that to the GUI tool, which would take sometimes 3-5 minutes to empty everything. This is for about 1.5GB of files.

Comment: Can also confirm that emptying via the GUI is a few orders of magnitude slower than via `rm -rf`.

Comment: This answer, speculating that emptying the bin on macOS doesn't actually delete things, but is actually like putting stuff into the bin, misunderstands what the bin does. Perhaps this might have to do with a difference between 'bin', 'trash', and 'recycle bin' over different OSes, but they all describe the same thing. Speculation should at least be in the right ballpark to receive an upvote.

Comment: @ifly6, instead of speculating how much people know about what they say, have you actually used any kind of Unix-like system and their associated GUIs to actually explain what happens under the hood instead of debating how much someone deserves and upvote or something else? Your own answer would be much more appreciated, maybe even useful.

Comment: `If you use a GUI tool instead (I suppose you are referring to it when you say "click empty trash") it is probably saving or moving these files somewhere else so you can possibly undelete them` is internally inconsistent. Resolve that issue in your answer.

Comment: Take a look at yourself dude! I'm not taking any orders from you. Use your "great knowledge" and teach us all in detail how it really works in your own answer, since you seem to think you know it all.